# special characters when accessing textarea contents in php

Tags: php, string, textarea, forms

I am getting special characters from the textarea input on my form

So if I enter the below text

> Philbrick, whose “In the Heart of the Sea: The Tragedy of the
>   Whaleship Essex” recounted the real-life inspiration for Melville’s
>   shipwreck, wears his erudition lightly.

I get the following when I access it in php.

> Philbrick, whose â€œIn the Heart of the Sea: The Tragedy of the
>   Whaleship Essexâ€ recounted the real-life inspiration for
>   Melvilleâ€™s shipwreck, wears his erudition lightly.

I tried the below before accessing the text , but replace is not working. Are these special characters not matching when I
am copy pasting those in the code or its something else which is missing?

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($_POST["t"]) ;
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$string = str_replace('â€œ', "\"", $string);
$string = str_replace('â€™', "'", $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be anything wrong with what you're seeing. You may not need to mangle the $_POST with htmlentities corrections or otherwise. It could be that you're looking at a barebones browser output.

In case you're debugging this by spitting it out with something like `print_r( $_POST ); die;`, make sure that somewhere above it in your page you have a meta line setting your character encoding to UTF-8:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

That will ensure that the smart characters (presumably pasted from somewhere) render properly on screen.

*Completely unrelated: Excellent book, BTW. Love the beginning scene with gaunt sailors hoarding their piles of bones.*

Answer (score 1):

You actually have not an ordinary single and double quotes, but some fancy unicode version:
&#x201c; &#x201d &#x2019

Try `utf8_decode`. BTW what encoding do you use, `Windows-1250`?

Comment: How to find which encoding is being used? I tried utf8_decode it produced : Philbrick, whose ?In the Heart of the Sea: The Tragedy of the Whaleship Essex? recounted the real-life inspiration for Melville?s shipwreck, wears his erudition lightly. So now special characters in the output are different?

Comment: echo "Encoding scheme is:" . mb_detect_encoding($string); produced UTF-8